# how to get the <a>under the <p>

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to get the a tag under the specific p tag.

I have tried this but is not working. I am trying to change the CSS style of the link part to red color and came with a red dot line when hovering the line will become solid.

```
var font_8 = document.getElementsByClassName('font_8');var elements = font_8.getElementsByTagName('a');
```

html:

```
    <p class="font_7" style="font-size:16px">text text text text<br>
<span style="text-decoration:underline"><a href="URL-link" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener">link link link</a></span>（text）</p>
    <p class="font_8" style="font-size:16px">text text text text<br>
<span style="text-decoration:underline"><a href="URL-link" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener">link link link</a></span>（text）</p>
```

js:

```
 <script>
    const styles = {
      textDecoration: 'none',
      color: 'red',
      borderBottom: '2px dotted currentColor',
    }
    
    function getElements() {
      var font_8 = document.getElementsByClassName('font_8');var elements = font_8.getElementsByTagName('a');
      var len = elements.length;
      for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
          Object.keys(styles).forEach((key)=>{
            elements[i].style[key]=styles[key]
          })
      }
      for (let i = 0; i < len; i++){
          elements[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
            elements[i].style.borderBottom= '2px solid currentColor';
          })
          elements[i].addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
            Object.keys(styles).forEach((key)=>{
              elements[i].style[key]=styles[key]
            })
          })
      }
    }
    
    getElements()
    </script>
```

Comment: You want the <a> under the <p> AND for it to be styled a certain way? These are two separate issues?

Comment: You should be using CSS for this, not javascript

Comment: yes, it can be done by CSS, just to practice my Javascript.

I try to change the .font_8 a tag style.

Comment: Oh I see, it's just for learning purposes. I will add JS to my answer then

Comment: You're conflating elements with tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using JavaScript just to learn, this is my solution with a [query selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector):

```js
const styles = {
  textDecoration: 'none',
  color: 'red',
  borderBottom: '2px dotted currentColor',
}
const normalStyle = 'dotted'
const hoverStyle = 'solid'

function applyStylesAndHover() {
  // querySelectorAll allows you to basically use a CSS selector in your JS
  const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.font_8 a');

  elements.forEach((element) => {
    Object.keys(styles).forEach((key) => {
      element.style[key] = styles[key]
    })
    element.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
      element.style.borderBottomStyle = normalStyle;
    })
    element.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
      element.style.borderBottomStyle = hoverStyle;
    })
  })
}
applyStylesAndHover()
```

```html
<p class="font_7" style="font-size:16px">
  text text text text
  <br>
  <span style="text-decoration:underline">
  <a href="URL-link" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener">link</a>
  </span>（text)
</p>
<p class="font_8" style="font-size:16px">
  text text text text
  <br>
  <span>
  <a href="URL-link" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener">link</a>
  </span>（text)
</p>
```

Although To style the <a> on hover you do not need JavaScript.
CSS is perfect for this:

```css
.font_8 a { /* An <a> inside of an element with the class of font_8 */
  color: red;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid red;
}

.font_8 a:hover { /* An <a> that is being hovered inside of an element with the class of font_8 */
  border-bottom-style: dotted;
}
```

```html
<p class="font_7" style="font-size:16px">
  text text text text
  <br>
  <span style="text-decoration:underline">
  <a href="URL-link" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener">link</a>
  </span>（text)
</p>
<p class="font_8" style="font-size:16px">
  text text text text
  <br>
  <span>
  <a href="URL-link" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener">link</a>
  </span>（text)
</p>
```

Comment: I just try to get the elements from the specific tag, when the elements don't have the id or class name. like, get the a tag then under the .font_8.

Comment: @ying query selectors are your CSS friend in JS land. They let you use a CSS selector to match one or more elements!

Answer (score 0):

One problem i found here is you are tring to get `<a>` using `font_8.getElementsByTagName('a');` which will not work. u will need to assign id to the a tag and get it by using

`var element = document..getElementsById('myAncor');`

and To move it inside p tag u will need to append the `element` to `font_8` using `.appenChild()`.

***edit:***
*sry i misunderstood ur question.*

to do this with JS use

```
var element= font_8[0].children[1].children[0];
element.addEventListener(
 // your core
)
```

or

```
var elements= document.querySelectorAll('.font_8 a');
//Your code
elements[i].addEventListener(
 // your core
)
```

Comment: What makes you think `font_8.getElementsByTagName('a');` will not work?

Comment: i tried running it on codepen and gave me an error

Comment: Oh right! It's because font_8 wasn't an element, since they used `getElementsByClassName('font_8')`

Comment: I think `document.querySelectorAll(.font_8 a)` is a better solution

Comment: yes agreed @ZachJensz I have added that too now

Comment: Thank you for both of you taking the time, I learned a lot^^